# Searching for unique dates in a log file (python)

Tags: python

I'm writing a script that parses log files and matches certain strings like "INFO", "WARN", "SEVERE", etc.

I can do this with out much trouble using the code below.

```
from sys import argv
from collections import OrderedDict

# Find and catalog each log line that matches these strings
match_strings = ["INFO", "WARN", "SEVERE"]

if len(argv) > 1:
    files = argv[1:]
else:
    print "ERROR: You must provide at least one log file to be processed."
    print "Example:"
    print "%s my.log" % argv[0]
    exit(2)

for filename in files:
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = f.read().splitlines()
        # Create data structure to handle results
        matches = OrderedDict()
        for string in match_strings:
            matches[string] = []

    for i, s in enumerate(data, 1):
        for string in match_strings:
            if string in s:
                matches[string].append('Line %03d: %s' % (i, s,))
for string in matches:
    print "\"%s\": %d" % (string, len(matches[string]))
```

Log files look like:

```
2014-05-26T15:06:14.597+0000 INFO...
2014-05-26T15:06:14.597+0000 WARN...
2014-05-27T15:06:14.597+0000 INFO...
2014-05-28T15:06:14.597+0000 SEVERE...
2014-05-29T15:06:14.597+0000 SEVERE...
```

Current output looks like:

```
"INFO": 2
"WARN": 1
"SEVERE": 2
```

However, what I'd rather do is have the script collate and print formatted output by date. So, rather than print a simple list (above) we could get something like the following using the sample from above:

```
Category    2014-05-26  2014-05-27  2014-05-28  2014-05-29

"INFO":         1           1           0           0
"WARN":         1           0           0           0
"SEVERE":       0           0           1           1
```

Are there any thoughts / suggestions how to accomplish this?

Comment: So have you actually *tried* anything at all in that direction?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes - I I tried using replacement fields which helped with the formatting of the output, but I've stumped with how to make the dates the headers of each column, etc.

Comment: Given that there are likely to be more dates than categories, wouldn't it make sense to have the latter as the columns? Look into e.g. [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to simplify the counting.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to make a class that has variables info, warn, and severe in it. Then make a dictionary where each element is this class with the key being the date. Then when you are parsing your log file you can just find the date and use that as the index for your dictionary and increment the info, warn, and severe as needed.